# Group posts by categories in custom taxonomy archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom taxonomy that is called `colture` and I am working on its archive template. The pages correctly display the posts of every term of the taxonomy "colture". Now I need to group them by default categories top-levels (there are 3 top levels) within the single term "colture" pages. I just need to put an `<h1>` (the one with class `titolo-applicazioni`) on top of each group.

One thing that might be considered is that the loop I made also group 3 posts per row within a div (with classes `row` and `prodotti`).

I tried nesting two queries: the top-level category query inside the custom taxonomy query in order to first display the posts within a certain taxonomy term and then group them by top-level categories.

The loop I am attaching here just repeats every post (all the posts with the current term) for every top-level category (every posts three times consequently) without grouping anything.

What am I missing?

```
<?php 
if (is_tax() || is_category() || is_tag() ){
$qobj = get_queried_object();

$args = array(
  'parent' => 0,
  'orderby' => 'rand',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => $qobj->taxonomy,
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => $qobj->term_id,
    )
  )
);

$random_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($random_query->have_posts()) {

?>
  <h1 class="titolo-applicazioni"><?php echo $category->slug;?></h1>
<?php

$i = 1;
echo '<div class="row prodotti">';

while ($random_query->have_posts()) {
$random_query->the_post();

    $cat_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'hide_empty'=> 0,
    'parent'       => 0,
);

$categories = get_categories($cat_args);
foreach ($categories as $cat) {

?>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
<!-- POST CONTENT -->
</div>

<?php if($i % 3 == 0) {echo '</div><div class="row prodotti">';}
$i++;?>

<?php 
} /* FOREACH */
} /* WHILE $RANDOM_QUERY HAS POSTS */
} /* IF $RANDOM_QUERY HAS POSTS */
} /* IF IS TAX */
?>
```